# angularjs injector:unpr error for location.path

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing

I am using $location.path but I have injected $location, I still cannot figure out what's causing the problem getting injector unknow provider error.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.controller("headerController", headerController);

    headerController.$inject = ['$scope','$location', '$http', '$rootScope', '$q'];

    function headerController($scope, $location, $http, $rootScope, $q) {
        var vm = this;

        $scope.search = function () {
            $location.path('/searchIndex').search({ query: $scope.query }); //Error At this line
        }
    }
})();
```

Error:

```
angular.js:15018 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams%20%3C-%20searchResultsController
    at angular.js:99
    at angular.js:4891
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:5051)
    at angular.js:4896
    at d (angular.js:5051)
    at e (angular.js:5076)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5120)
    at angular.js:11175
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular.js:1364 "<div class="well ng-scope" ui-view="">"
```

app.js

```
(function () {

    var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

    myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/homeIndex")


                $stateProvider.state('searchIndex', {
                    url: "/searchIndex",
                    templateUrl: "SOC/Views/Search/index.html",
                    controller: "searchResultsController"
                })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    });


})();
```

SearchResultsController for this angularjs application

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');

    app.controller('searchResultsController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$rootScope', '$q', '$routeParams',
      function ($scope, $location, $http, $rootScope, $q, $routeParams) {
          var vm = this;

          $scope.query = $routeParams.query;
          $scope.url = $location.absUrl();


          $scope.results = [];

          $http.get($scope.url).then(function (result) { if (result.data.contains($scope.query)) $scope.results.push("url1") });

      }
    ]);
})();
```

Please suggest if I a missing anything, even i spelled all the injections correctly

Answer (score 0):

*(It has been a while since i've used ui-router, but I think I see the problem)*

It appears you're using a combination of ui-router and the standard angular router.

When you perform a url change, you should be using `$state.go(...)` instead of `$location.path(...)`  Also, when registering your states in your config, you should do `$stateProvider.state(...)` and not `$urlRouterProvider.state(...)` (not sure if this will make a difference, but thats what the wiki has in its examples.

**app.js:**

```
// For any unmatched url, send to /homeIndex
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/homeIndex");

$stateProvider
        .state('searchIndex', {
            url: "/searchIndex",
            templateUrl: "SOC/Views/Search/index.html",
            controller: "searchResultsController"
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.search = function () {
    $state.go('searchIndex', { query: $scope.query });
}
```

**See:**

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: I am still getting same error even after fixing as you have suggested

Comment: I have injected `$state`

Comment: This time i am getting same error at the flower brackets when search function is exiting

Comment: The issue may be within the creation of `searchResultsController`, perhaps look at that / upload the contents of that controller too

Comment: I have added searchResultsController in question

Comment: If you're using ui-router, you should us `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams`.

Comment: if I use `$stateParams.query;` i am not getting  `scope.query` value. How to get that $scope.query value

Comment: It because searchcontroller when loaded first value is undefined